# Of the 34 Conservatives who voted against the Withdrawal Agreement last time, how many are remainers?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, house-of-commons, conservative-party

There were [34 Conservatives](https://commonsvotes.digiminster.com/Divisions/Details/664?byMember=false#noes) who voted against May's last attempt (that was put to a vote) on March 29 to pass the Withdrawal Agreement she agreed with EU.

I recognized only one remainer on that list: Dominic Grieve. Are there any other?

Comment: Do we have a facility to do community answers on this stack? Might work better than someone researching all of the listed names.

Comment: https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2019/may/25/tory-leadership-race-cyanide-brexit-inequality Justine Greening is remain leaning.

Comment: @Jontia: when answering, tick "community wiki" to the bottom right of the form. Don't forget to start your answer by raising it's a "community wiki" answer, else you'll invariably get other people providing new answers with this or that forgotten name.

Comment: Dropped the community wiki after finding the FT page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what you mean by remainer, several pro-Brexit MPs have been labelled Remainers for voting [FOR](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/brexit-david-davies-tory-mp-bbc-interview-watch-leave-supporter-a8924601.html) May's deal.

That said, the most succinct definition is probably those in favour of a 2nd Referendum. The list on the FT article on Conservative [Tribes](https://ig.ft.com/brexit-tory-tribes/) is a little out of date as it comes from before the creation of The Independent Group, now known as Change UK.

Still sticking with that list, all of them voted against the Government and they are;

- Dominic Grieve
- Justine Greening
- Phillip Lee
- Sam Gyimah
- Guto Bebb
- Jo Johnson

The rest of the listed Tribe defected to the new Change UK where they also voted No in this instance.

So in a direct answer; 6 Remainer Conservative MPs voted against May's deal in Meaningful vote 3.

Comment: Four of these six also publicly opposed Brexit in the run-up to the 2016 referendum. For Sam Gyimah and Jo Johnson there is no info on their pre-2016-referendum position on their Wikipedia profile. Wikipedia actually fails to identify Greening's 2016 position as well, but it can be found separately https://medium.com/christian-aid-eu-referendum/eu-referendum-remain-or-leave-justine-greening-mp-has-her-say-ebcbaa660a2

Comment: Also [according to WaPo](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/europe/boris-johnsons-family-is-in-a-row-over-brexit/2018/11/12/7635b9f6-e682-11e8-8449-1ff263609a31_story.html) Jo Johnson voted remain in 2016. And Sam Gyimah was also remainer then http://www.samgyimah.com/2016/02/22/eu-referendum-my-position/ So all six were remainers in 2016.

Comment: @Fizz I am not sure the 2016 positions are the best guide. [Matt Hancock](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-eu-referendum-35616946) for instance voted remain in 2016, there is no shade of that in his Twitter stream today.

Comment: Although I guess it is unlikely that a 2016 leaver MP is a remain supporter today